# Problem with NSTimer called inside my -parserDidEndDocument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I have a NSTimer object.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[timer fire];
```

The method 'timerAction' repeats perfectly when call the timer from viewDidLoad method, but when I call the timer from parserDidEndDocument, the method 'timerAction' runs only once. Why is this?

Comment: You need to post the code inside your parserDidEndDocument calling the timer. Otherwise how would I guess?

Comment: Above code fragment it is. That's what I have put in the parserDidEnd. Even in the viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try running the timer on the main thread.

> Try this

create a new method that includes the code, to start timer, like :-

```
-(void)createTimer{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.02 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
}
```

In Your `parserDidEndDocument` delegate, try this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createTimer) withObject:[nil waitUntilDone:YES]
```

Comment: Genius! This is worked!!! Thank you.
So this is about running on the main thread. 
There was a tiny bug in the your code, its fixed under
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(createTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: I am glad, it helps. The issue was related to threading, as the parsing in not done on the main thread. So its always a good idea to perform allocations and UIKit related tasks on the main thread, and let it handle the things accordingly